# The idiom “be a thing”

Tags: etymology, idioms, language-evolution

I’m looking for the origin of the idiom “to be a thing”. It means roughly “exist” or more specifically “be recognised” or “be a phenomenon”. I first noticed it around 2008–2009.

> - [Is medical grade tea a thing?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6995604)
> - [I don’t think that is a thing](http://sanfrancisco.granicus.com/TranscriptViewer.php?view_id=99&clip_id=18499), but I just don’t think that it should be mandatory
> - Unlocking accomplishments? [I don’t think that is a thing.](https://tagn.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/drone-assist-slaughter-at-bw-wj2/)
> - [Is That a Thing?](http://isthatathing.tumblr.com/)
> - [I didn’t know that was a thing.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=A%20Thing&defid=6324489)
> - a tech startup cto who doesn’t know how to code / [yes, that is a thing :(](https://twitter.com/bengold/status/408367565216702464)

It *seems* to come from the use of *thing* in the sense of a popular phenomenon—cf. “Ecigs are the new thing”. However, its meaning also extends to differentiating set phrases, names, or terms of art from normal productive constructions. For example:

> — If you assign the mutable reference…
>   — Is that a thing? *[Is “mutable reference” different from “mutable” + “reference”?]*
>   — Hm? Oh, no, a variable can be mutable or be a reference, or both; they’re separate.
>   — Oh, okay. So if we assign this here…

So I’m wondering how it was originally used and whether any authorities recognise it yet.

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb; it's a predicate noun. _Thing_ is the predicate and _be_ is the auxiliary verb. Just like _be a doctor_.

Comment: I have heard the expression "it is already a thing" used to say that something that exists or is already happened has an appreciable value or it is not  negligible at all.

Comment: That's been a thing for a while.

Comment: *Jon has a **thing** for idiomatic usages*. In this case I think *that's a thing* is usually just a trivial rewording of *that [thing] exists*, and *that's **the** thing* is effectively short for *that's the **important** thing*.

Comment: I'd guess this fairly recent use is related to the rise of internet memes.

Comment: @Hugo - yeah, they're a thing nowadays.

Comment: Another one that came up recently: “highly sensitive person”, despite not sounding like a thing, is a thing.

Comment: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/06/become-a-thing/

Comment: I hate this doltish-sounding construct so much. In 2017, it has definitely risen to the level of insufferability. Now, coinciding with the increased lack of professionalism in headlines and journalism, I've received an alert from my local NBC news channel's app asking why "DST is even still a thing." I suppose at this rate, within another 20 years, most people will speak and write like Valley Girls with traumatic brain injuries. In short, please don't propagate this, if you can help it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd guess this fairly recent use is related to the rise of internet memes, and whether an item is widespread or just someone's own: "Is this a thing? Is this a trend?"

It dates back to at least 2006 on blogs and 2001 in film and television.

---

The second [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=A%20Thing&defid=6324489) definition is relevant:

> **2. A Thing**
>
> An action, fashion style, philosophy, musical genre, or other popularly recognized subsection of popular culture. Normally used in surprise at it's existence. Becomes official when a wikipedia article is created for it.
>
> *"Whats the deal with those skin-tight body suits?"
>
>   "Oh, you mean Zentai?
>
>   "Huh. I didn't know that was a thing."*
>
> [thing] [something] [noun] [unknown] [popular] [pop culture]
>   by mrpeach32 December 29, 2011 
>   82 up, 18 down

---

### 2006 blogs

It dates at least from 2006. Here's a March 2006 [blog comment](http://www.sadlyno.com/archives/2496.html#comment-8940):

> Sifu Tweety said,
>   March 29, 2006 at 22:16
>
> A) How did the skull get in your ass? Is this a thing? Are there websites? Please don’t tell me about them.

And a [blog comment](http://www.amalah.com/amalah/2006/04/the_other_very_.html#comment-15770215) from April 2006:

> Good god, it's like people lie in wait, pressing refresh, waiting to comment. Is this a thing?
>
> Posted by: Meg | April 03, 2006 at 10:48 PM

Here's a one from November 2006 on the [Guardian's film blog](http://www.theguardian.com/film/filmblog/2006/nov/16/whathasvincevaughneverdon):

> In the  changing room of the gym, there are a large group of twittering women standing around. I'm mainly blocking them out, but suddenly, the whirr of the hairdryers dies down, and one phrase leaps out of the burble...
>
> "...and you know, you'd think it would be really good. Because it's got Vince Vaughn in it."
>
> What?
>
> Is that a *thing*? Is it really? Is it a thing that people would naturally assume, seeing Vince Vaughn above the title of a new release?

---

The Straight Dope Message Board covered ["Is this a thing?"](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=653604) with one saying they first heard "Is that even a thing?" on *Seinfeld* (1989 - 1998) but [I couldn't](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awww.seinfeldscripts.com%20%22even%20a%20thing%22) [find it](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=seinfeld&imdb=&q=thing&search_sort=Popularity&genre=-1&type=All). Another said they'd heard "Is that even a thing?" on *Family Guy* but I couldn't find it there either.

A Lingua Franca post on ["I Guess ‘It’s a Thing’"](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/12/13/i-guess-its-a-thing/) found a 2001:

> The distinction has applied through the history of the phrase; and I’ll note that the “existence” meaning is an elision of the traditional “(there is/is there) such a thing as…” The first occurrence I’ve been able to find was in a 2001 episode of *That ’70s Show*, involving a pick-up basketball game:
>
> > *DONNA: Oh! That’s 16 for me and Hyde and four for the losers! You guys ought to get a mascot … a big, green, furry loser!*
> >
> > *ERIC: That’s … That’s not even a thing.*
>
> But that seems to have been an outlier, with the next use not occurring till February 2007, when the LAist blog asked: “Is jazzy folk even a thing?”

---

Finally, following on and searching more television and movies, here's *[The Adventures of Pluto Nash](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/The+Adventures+of+Pluto+Nash/There+Iies+your+probIem.+That%27s+not+even%0D%0A+a+thing.+Did+you+make+that+up?)* (2002):

> 00:03:41 No, a kilt. That's how people know who I am.
>   00:03:43 People think of Anthony Frankowski, they immediately think ''Scottish crooning.''
>   00:03:48 There lies your problem. That's not even a thing. Did you make that up?
>   00:03:52 Yes, I made that up. It's a thing if I made it up.

Comment: Are all those references, including the blogs and so forth, original research? If so, I'm impressed. You should work for a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

from [Online Etymology](http://etymonline.com/index.php?l=t&p=15&allowed_in_frame=0):

> thing (n.): Old English þing "meeting, assembly," later "entity, being, matter" (subject of deliberation in an assembly), also "act, deed, event, material object, body, being," from Proto-Germanic *thengan "appointed time" (cf. Old Frisian thing "assembly, council, suit, matter, thing," Middle Dutch dinc "court-day, suit, plea, concern, affair, thing," Dutch ding "thing," Old High German ding "public assembly for judgment and business, lawsuit," German ding "affair, matter, thing," Old Norse þing "public assembly"). Some suggest an ultimate connection to PIE root *ten- "stretch," perhaps on notion of "stretch of time for a meeting or assembly."
>
> Used colloquially since c.**1600** to indicate things **the speaker can't name** at the moment, often with various meaningless suffixes, e.g. thingumbob (1751), thingamajig (1824). Southern U.S. pronunciation thang attested from 1937. **The thing "what's stylish or fashionable" is recorded from 1762**. Phrase do your thing "follow your particular predilection," though associated with hippie-speak of 1960s is attested from ***1841***.

I can't do better than this. Lucky find as it was.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question.

Comment: '**The thing "what's stylish or fashionable" is recorded from 1762**' appears possibly relevant, but the dictionary does not make it obvious it is talking about the same idiom.

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed this expression in the past 2 years or so.  Most recently, a coworker talking about when a corporate IT system will be up and running - "when it's a thing."   I agree that "to be a thing" is being used as a verb phrase meaning "to exist."  I guess that if it isn't a person or a place, it must be a thing, even if it's an abstract concept.

Answer (score -4):

I am not a native English speaker. But I heard that "thing" comes from "think". In the sense mentioned above it is something you can't name yet but you think about. I wonder if it is the etymological origin of "thing".

Comment: Whether or not this etymology is correct, that's not the sense it's being used in here. It isn't used as a pronoun, but rather to question whether some thing is a member of the set of things which exist, and usually more specifically exist as a repeating phenomenon or as an element of culture or subculture.

Comment: Etymology is certainly incorrect.